# Photoshop Alternatives for G5 Macs

Tags: adobe-photoshop, software-recommendation

I'm in the market for an alternative to Photoshop for my G5 tower.  I tried GIMP and I'm a bit blah about it; are there any other options that you can recommend?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Due to the expense of Photoshop, I bought Pixelmator a year or so ago. I only do photo-editing with it, so I can't comment on using it for design, but it has been powerful enough for me.

http://www.pixelmator.com/

I'm not sure if Pixelmator can run on pre-Intel macs, though.

Comment: While otherwise an alternative, Pixelmator requires Mac OS X 10.6 Snow Leopard (or later) which doesn't run on pre-Intel (PowerPC) Macs.

Comment: Huh. I bought it when the latest version was 10.4. I guess they don't offer old versions, though.

Comment: Definitely considering this one for my laptop, but yeah, not G5 compatible at the present time unfortunately.

Comment: I've been eying Pixelmator. Seems to be a great value. How's it handling Photoshop layers?

Comment: If you mean importing from Photoshop, I have no idea. I've never tried to import a Photoshop file. Sorry.

Answer (score 4):

What about an older version of Photoshop? I think CS2 was the last which supported G5s.

Comment: I've got CS2 on there right now, but unfortunately the license recently decided it expired and my brother has long-since misplaced the registration info for it.  If you know a good place to pick up a copy on the cheap, though, I'm all ears!

Answer (score 3):

Depends for what Photoshop functionality you need.

For simple tasks, maybe [Aviary Phoenix](http://www.aviary.com/tools/image-editor) could do the job.

[image: aviary phoenix interface]

In the same area:
[Pixlr](http://www.pixlr.com/editor/)

[image: Pixlr interface]

and [Adobe Photoshop Express Editor](http://www.photoshop.com/tools?wf=editor)

[image: Potoshop Express Editor]

Answer (score 2):

Check out [Alternativeto.net](http://alternativeto.net/software/adobe-photoshop/?profile=mac&platform=mac) for a list, among them are pixelmator, gimp, pixel, and others.